# Why are all the Site Settings links which have a {AnyToken} in the url returning a connection reset error in my SharePoint 2013 application?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

Why are all the Site Settings links which have a {AnyToken} in the url returning a connection reset error in my SharePoint 2013 application?

Examples:

- Master pages and page layouts
  https://hostmane/_layouts/15/RedirectPage.aspx?Target={SiteCollectionUrl}_catalogs/masterpage
- Content and structure
  https://hostmane/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx?Source={WebUrl}_layouts/15/settings.aspx

The error message is:

This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem was not in the SharePoint application.

The error happens every time the link has an accolade "{}" in the URL, for example:

```
https://domain/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx?Source={WebUrl}_layouts/15/settings.aspx
```

Even if I add a dummy query string:

```
https://domain/?test={test}
```

But when I encode the accolade changing { to %7B and } to %7D, both URLs work fine:

```
https://domain/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx?Source=%7BWebUrl%7D_layouts/15/settings.aspx
https://domain/?test=%7Btest%7D
```

Also, when I test it locally in the server via Remote Desktop using a localhost address it works even with an unencoded accolade. For example,

```
http://localhost:1000/default.aspx?test={test}
```

Based in those observations, I assigned the problem to network security responsible and he created a rule in the firewall to avoid blocking an access attempt when there are unencoded accolade characters in the URL.